# monoDevelop: Which is the last version of monoDevelop an dhow can install it?

Tags: monodevelop

I am using ubuntu 16.04 i386 and I am noticed monodevelop the latest version is 6.0.

Is it right? I have monoDevelop 5.10 and I would love to upgrade latest version. Using check updates doesn't tell me any neew version.

or maybe 5.10 it is really the latest

can anybody help me please to know which is the latest and install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonoDevelop Version=6.2 is the *latest as of today*, but you review the current version @:

- https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/version.config

Consult the `Linux distribution packages` section for pre-packaged versions:

- http://www.monodevelop.com/download/

The latest *official* package from Ubuntu is *5.10.0.871-2*

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=monodevelop

If you want to get the latest and greatest, you can either install from the Continuous Integration packages or from source:

- http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/ci-packages/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives
- https://github.com/mono/monodevelop

Comment: just one question ... why is so difference the version of monoDevelop of Ubuntu and Windows (or mac)?

Comment: Different? In which aspect?

Comment: in windows version is 6 right (p.e.) and in Ubuntu is (5.10) that difference... you said: The latest official package from Ubuntu is 5.10.0.871-2

Comment: Various Linux distos have different processes for packaging third-party applications. Some take the **last major stable** release and only release security patches to that release, some track the latest version, etc....It really is determined by the disto packager and the disto package rules. The *odds* are that the next major Ubuntu release will include a 6.1 (or maybe 6.2) version of MonoDevelop and track security releases for that release. If you want the latest and greatest for the disto that you are using, you typically will have to handle it yourself.

Comment: I really love program .net in monodevelop nice IDE